# using udpcast over the internet

Tags: networking, udp

can I use udpcast-receiver to send file from my office in one country to a different branch located in another country? if so what options should I use? I tried nc - netcat with tcp it works but with udp it doesnt. I need to send files of varying size from 1kb - 3gb

Comment: You are trying to broadcast to the entire internet?

Comment: No, but to a specific ip as in netcat

Comment: What exact error messages are you getting?

Comment: If you are just looking for a way to transfer files between two computers in two separate locations across the Internet, there are better choices. I think most people would use scp for occasional/ad-hoc use, and maybe set up an sftp server for more routine use.

Comment: @harrymc : UDPcast works perfectly when I tried to broadcast a file and receive it in my colleague's PC as we are in the same LAN. My concern is that to send the files to a windows PC in another country(in Europe in a different domain). I don't see any error messages as such but connection doesn't start as it did in local LAN.

Comment: @Spiff: I tried windows to win ftp(setup my pc as ftp server) but its very slow. I prefer to use low level tools with UDP to increase the copy time. Hence other tools are of not any interest to me.

Comment: @harrymc : Additionally I am concerned with the below statement from udpcast homepage - "UDPcast is a file transfer tool that can send data simultaneously to many destinations on a LAN"

Comment: I suspect you just used a crappy FTP implementation. Try using IPerf to test TCP and UDP performance between offices (note: IPerf by default *sends* from the client instance to the server instance, so you need the remote branch machine to run IPerf in server mode, while in your local office you run IPerf in client mode). If the numbers come out about the same, you'll have disproved your UDP belief. If TCP is significantly slower than UDP, post your results and I'll teach you how to fix your TCP tuning problem or your bufferbloat problem. UDP can only beat TCP by making congestion worse.